# SAP Crystal Reports Invalid Argument provided

Tags: java, java-8, crystal-reports, classpath

Hello my favorite people!

I received a new laptop with Windows 11.  I've installed Crystal 2016 (SP09), installed JDK, went through all installations. These are the same versions on the tomcat server so I *think* I should be using the same so there are no issues when I mess with CRs.

I keep getting this error every time I open the Crystal reports on my new laptop.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Error:

> Invalid Argument provided. Details: Java Server startup failure. Verify the PATH (JDK), CLASSPATH, and IORFileLocation properties in the CRConfig.xml file. In addition, verify that you are using JDK 1.5.
>
> [image]

I compared everything between my old laptop with Windows 10 and it all looks exactly the same. I even copied over the Java folder (`C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP BusinessObjects\SAP BusinessObjects Enterprise XI 4.0\java`) which included the `CRConfig.xml` file and moved it from the old to the new laptop but same results. I'm convinced it's Windows 11 but I haven't found the cause.

Comment: Have you checked the SAP support website for this?  There appears to be a Knowledge Base Article about this specific error and how to troubleshoot, but for some reason I'm unable to access the article through my login.

You may also need to verify you have the correct JDBC installed, or you may need to reinstall it as well.  This error is usually due to a failure to connect to the database through JDBC.

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong, but my hunch here is that you copied files over to your new laptop that reference your old Java executable. Make sure Java is installed on your new system and see if you can update that reference (likely in a config file). If that doesnt work, consider reinstalling the software.

Comment: It did not work. I even uninstalled 2016, found and installed CR 2020 and STILL get this error!  I am so confused here. Still looking for a solution.